# why is my left and right column not scrollable

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a three column in a `column-fluid container`. My right and left column are fixed, but not scrollable though I have placed `overflow-y:scroll`

```
.row > .sidebar-fixed {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left:auto;
    width: 220px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}

.left {
    float:left;
}

.right {
    float:right;
}

.fixed-fixed {
    margin: 0 240px;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/UfYNttcqhS#

How can I make my `right and left column` scrollable vertically.

Comment: I see disabled scrollbars in each of the left and right columns. What are you seeing?

Comment: @Mooseman: the same... but how come its disabled... when I have specified overflow-y:scroll;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scrollbars appear disabled because there is no content to be scrolled.

I changed your CSS...

```
.row > .sidebar-fixed{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 220px;
  height: 100%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
.row > .sidebar-fixed.left{
    left:0;
}
.row > .sidebar-fixed.right{
    right:0;
}

.fixed-fixed {
    margin: 0 240px;
}
```

...added filler text...

```
  <div class="well sidebar-fixed left">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  </div><!--/.well -->
```

...and updated [the demo](http://www.bootply.com/X0Bie7aRN0).

Comment: Its working perfectly, but now the container goes above the nav bar.

Comment: Is it fine to remove the top:0 as I want this to be placed below the navbar.

Comment: If you change `top: 0;` to `top:***px`, change `height: 100%;` to `bottom: 0;` as to not overflow the viewport.

Answer (score 2):

You have to place some content inside of that div and make the height on it more than the height of the scrollable div like this:

```
<div class="well sidebar-fixed left">
            <div id="overflow">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce non nisl faucibus lacus malesuada lobortis. Nulla sapien diam, convallis quis arcu hendrerit, tempus facilisis nibh. Donec interdum lacus eget sapien facilisis, et congue urna tristique. Maecenas ante tellus, euismod quis adipiscing sed, elementum in lorem. Donec venenatis dui a lobortis iaculis. Curabitur pulvinar blandit magna at dictum. Maecenas nec sodales eros, at vestibulum mauris. Phasellus vitae ante at erat semper gravida. Maecenas tincidunt elementum eros, ut feugiat justo viverra a. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla gravida elementum dui eu aliquet. Nunc vulputate urna fringilla, mollis ipsum non, fermentum diam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aliquam leo tellus, auctor id justo nec, lobortis dignissim metus. Phasellus eleifend ac lacus non blandit. Quisque eu purus sagittis, gravida odio ut, congue diam.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
```

And in the css:

```
.row > .sidebar-fixed {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left:auto;
    width: 220px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more Bootstrap-friendly (responsive grid) approach:

### [Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/yuZOh7Or9m)

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
   height: 100%; 
}
.container-fluid.main {
    padding-top: 50px;
    height: 100%;
}
.container-fluid.main>.row {
    height: 100%;
}    
.left, .right {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    overflow: auto;        
}

@media (max-width: 767px) { /*set to where your columns will collapse to 100%*/
    .left, .right {
      height: auto;   
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid main">
  <!-- Example row of columns -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 left">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
      
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
   </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 right">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this one.... it was a nice refresh. actually setting height to 100% in html, body is breaking other pages.